# Insert textbox and drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I want to keep the title and the genre of a movie for a further use. I'm trying to display the textbox and the dropdown menu only when I click the sentence 'insert a movie'.The dropdown menu appears before I click the sentence and I dont know how to change that.I also want somehow to keep the input values.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title >MOVIES </title> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML="<p><input type='text' name='title'>";
    }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
    <form>
    <h1 style="color:black">MOVIES </h1>
    </center>
    <ul> 
    <li> <a  onclick="myFunction()">Insert a movie </a>    </li>
    <p id="a"></p>



    <select name="mydropdown">
    <option value="Action">Action</option>
    <option value="Animation">Animation</option>
    <option value="Comedy">Comedy</option>
    <option value="Drama">Drama</option>
    <option value="Fantasy">Fantasy</option>
    <option value="Horror">Horror</option>
    <option value="Mystery">Mystery</option>
    <option value="Romance">Romance</option>
    <option value="Sci-fi">Sci-fi</option>
    <option value="War">War</option> 

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `myFunction` function, insert the following code:

```
var dropDownElement = document.createElement("select")

document.body.appendChild(dropDownElement);
```

Then do the same thing to insert all your options for the drop down list. You also may want to consider hiding the drop down list box at times. For that, you can use the `dropDownElement.style.display = "none";`